# Cannot change language to English in Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2

I am having difficulty changing the language settings to English in Windows Server 2012. I went to Administrator setting in Power Shell and typed Get-WinSystemLocale to display the locale information. Then I typed Set-WinSystemLocale en-US to set the locale for the region and language to English, United States. However, I keep getting

```
LCID         Name       DisplayName
----         ----       -----------
1033         en-US      Ingles (Estados Unidos)
```

Everything is in Portuguese. I even tried restarting the Windows Server 2012 after completing the transition on the power shell. Please help. Thank you!

Comment: Is English language support installed on the server? Presuming you installed in Portugese, you may need to install additional languages in order to be able to use them. My Windows 10 only has English language installed by default; I can add additional languages through the Control Panel, but I can't use them until I do so.

Comment: Read [Available Language Packs for Windows](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825678.aspx) and then [Add Language Packs to Windows](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825699.aspx)